# Retrieving an entire website using Google Cache?

Tags: google-search

There is a site that I want to retrieve from Google Cache that had thousands of pages. Is there any way I can get it back quickly using Google Cache or some other web crawler/archiver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see what Google (still) knows about a website by using a `site` restrict:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=site:[domain]
```

You might also check out the [Internet Archive](http://www.archive.org/).

(In either case, you’d probably want to do some heavy-duty automating to fetch thousands of pages.)

Comment: I was going to use Warrick: http://warrick.cs.odu.edu/

But alas, its servers are too busy. Internet Archive saves after 6 months.