# Do browsers store cached CSS files if so can I download the css file?

Tags: css, browser-cache

Our hosts have managed to delete our website somehow and I'm not sure whether they actually have any backups even though they say they have.

I have the database as this wasn't deleted, but most of our CSS files have been lost.

Im hoping that there is a way to download the cached version from a browser.

if possible how can I download the cached css file from a browser?

Thanks for any help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359882/retrieving-an-entire-website-using-google-cache

Comment: http://recovermywebsite.com/ a user posted in the question Bryce posted above.  Could help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to about:cache in chrome to shows all cached files.

Downloading cached files from other browsers works mostly the same.